# Remove order from ActiveRecord scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I'm using rails ransack ( https://github.com/ernie/ransack ) to allow the users to filter and sort some records.  I get the filtered and sorted records using traditional methods.

```
 @invoices = Invoice.search(params[:q]).result
```

Now I would like to get some summary information so I have

```
 @invoices = Invoice.search(params[:q]).result
 @summary = @invoices.select("sum(balance) as balance_total").first
```

Except when the user specifies a field to sort.  I get the SQL error:

```
 Column "project_name" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because 
 it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

Can I remove the sort from the scope?  How?

Thanks

Comment: hmmm now ransack isn't liking the select on the result set, not sure it worked without the sort issue anymore.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You can call the [reorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder) method with an empty string. E.g.:

```rb
Article.order('headline asc').to_sql
#=> "SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles`  ORDER BY headline asc"

Article.order('headline asc').reorder('').to_sql
#=> "SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles`"
```

Comment: Note: If it feels better to you, can also call `.reorder(nil)`.

Comment: Another option is to use `unscope(:order)`

Comment: And yet another option is to use `.except(:order)`.

Comment: For the `except(:order)` option official documentation can be found at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-except

Comment: I feel uneasy about `reorder('')` and `reorder(nil)` feels so good. Is there a psychological name for this?

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the `unscoped` class method in Rails 3:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :published => true
end

posts = Post.all #=> SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published = true

posts = Post.unscoped do
  Post.all #=> SELECT * FROM posts
end
```

In Rails 2 it was called `with_exclusive_scope`.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bd1666ad1de88598ed6f04ceffb8488a77be4385

Comment: A word of warning to people using `unscoped`: It does more than just reset the order! If you are using it in a chained ActiveRecord query, it will effectively remove the prior constraints from consideration.

For example, `Posts.first.comments.unscoped` will return ALL Comment's, not just those associated with the first Post.